# Unable to Ping Past Firewall

Tags: routing, fortigate

I am trying to get communication across a firewall, but I am unable to ping anything past the firewall.

PC1:172.16.201.22 <-> Router:172.16.192.1 <-> Firewall_Port1:10.10.10.4 <-> Firewall_Port2:192.168.11.201 <-> PC2:192.168.11.221

Router Config

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description
 ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.248
 ip access-group ESP_in in
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip route-cache
 standby 1 ip 10.10.10.1
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 mtu 9576
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.101
 encapsulation dot1Q 101
 ip address 172.16.96.2 255.255.240.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip route-cache
 standby 101 ip 172.16.96.1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.201
 encapsulation dot1Q 201
 ip address 172.16.192.2 255.255.240.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip route-cache
 standby 201 ip 172.16.192.1
!
!
ip route 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.4
ip route 172.16.96.0 255.255.240.0 10.10.10.4
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.4
ip route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.4
!
```

[Firewall Static IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxsS.jpg)

[image: Firewall Interface]

[image: Policies]

Comment: No policies? The Fortigate doesn't route anything without policy.

Comment: @Zac67 I do have policies... I'll post them

Comment: Please provide clear diagram. It looks like a routing error.

Comment: I don't see any route or interface on the fortinet to reach 172.16.201.22.

Comment: Have you checked the log? It should show the deny. If not, at least temporarily set the policy to log always. Also, check out the policy editor's *Policy Lookup* feature (both ways), it's very handy. The policy snapshot you posted is very cryptical and practically useless without the object definitions.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Device that I was trying to communicate with past firewall did not have Default Gateway IP configured...